# Google Calendar API with PHP and a Service Account won't work anymore

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I have a site with approximately 15 calendars that I connect to Google calendars using the Google Calendar API with PHP and a service account. I use just a plain old gmail account not a gsuite account. I use my site to add, edit and delete events on these calendars.

```
    function Google_Calendar_Connect(){
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Private_Key.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName("Mical");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
return $service;
}
$service = Google_Calendar_Connect();
$event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $Array["google_id"]);
$event->setSummary($Array2['fullName']);
$event->setLocation($Array['job_address']);
$event->setDescription($Array['description']);
try{
$updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);
}catch (Exception $ex)
        {echo $ex;
            // Event was not found on Google Calendar.
        } finally {
//if it worked, do something
}
```

Normally I would add the service account email into the calendar "share with people" setting with "Make changes to events" permission, this allows the script above to edit the calendar event.
Recently when I added a new calendar on Google and tried to add the service account email to the "share with people" setting, it would not allow me to do so.

I read on [Service Accounts don't accept automatically shared calendars anymore](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709) that it is a fix by Google because the service account cannot verify or approve itself.
Anyway, this now means that I can not add edit or delete events this new calendar or any new calendars that I create. It still works on the old calendars that were shared with the service account because they are still shared.

Can anyone recommend a fix or different way of connecting to the calendar without user interaction and without having to recreate new calendars in Gsuite ?

Answer (score 0):

## step one.

I would like you to check that the issue isnt simply that the calendar you are looking for is not appearing in your calendarlist,  it is correct that service accounts no longer insert automatically into the calendar list but that does not mean that you dont have access to the calendar.

Try and do something like this to add the calendar to calendarlist.  You should be able to find the calendar id from Google calendar web application.

```
$calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("calendarId");

$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

## option two

If as you say that you truly do not have access to the calendar anymore and the issue isn't simply that it wasn't added automatically for you to the calendar list.

The only work around for this would be to create a dummy Google user,  then using Oauth2 authenticate the user using Offline access, this will give you a refresh token.

You can then use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever you need to.  Using

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

This is not an ideal solution as refresh tokens can stop working although it is extremely rare it can happen so you will need to baby sit the code and have it notify you if it has any issues with its refresh token so that you can create a new one

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well originally. This question has more to do with connecting the service account email to the calendar to enable it to be edited. If the service account email cannot be added to the "share with people" setting on the calendars settings how can we now do that?

Comment: If they have removed that ability then you cant do it and must go with option number two unless you have a gsuite account.   Google is locking down what service accounts can do if they dont want you using them without gsuite anymore then there isnt much you can do.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up moving everything over to gsuite and it's all working perfectly.